# Copy content from a specific sheet in a workbook to another specific sheet in another workbook in same directory

Tags: excel, vba

**Background:**
I have two workbooks in the same directory with different sheets in each one of them.

I would like to open book2.xlsx, execute a VBA, to copy the whole content from "sheet1" in book1.xls. After this, the book1.xls should be closed automatically.

I have a code, which is moving the content next to a sheet, then I have to rename this sheet to the desired one. The problem with this is one is I the formulas in the other sheet will not work as desired. The code is as follows,

```
Sub XLVBACopyFiles()
    Dim MonthlyWB As Variant
    Dim FileName As String

    FileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    Path = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'Copy the sheet1 next to sheet2 in the current workbook

    Application.Workbooks.Open (Path & "book1.xls")
        Sheets(Array("sheet1")).Select
        Sheets("sheet1").Activate
        Sheets(Array("sheet1")).Move After:=Workbooks( _
            FileName).Sheets("sheet2")

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Workbooks(FileName).Save
    ' Workbooks(FileName).Close
End Sub
```

Any help with this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you give a couple of sample sheets with the offending formulas?. I have tested the sample code and found no errors...

Comment: Hello Antonio, The problem with this formulae is, that it will place the sheet next to "sheet2" because of the following line in the script (After:=Workbooks( _       FileName).Sheets("sheet2"))). However, I want it to be pasted to the sheet2 itself. Hope this, helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want , according to your comment above, is paste the content to "sheet2 itself", update the code above :

```
Application.Workbooks.Open (Path & "book1.xls")
        Sheets(Array("sheet1")).Select
        Sheets("sheet1").Activate
        **Sheets(Array("sheet1")).Move After:=Workbooks( _
            FileName).Sheets("sheet2")**
```

to

```
  Application.Workbooks.Open (Path & "book1.xls")
            Sheets(Array("sheet1")).Select
            Sheets("sheet1").Activate
            'Next 2 lines will select the range of content to be copied, and CTRL+C it. Edit it to your desire range
            Range("A1:A5").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Sheet2").Select
            Range("A1").Select ' In this line you should choose which cell to start pasting
            ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Also, to close workbook, use:

```
Workbooks("book1.xls").Close SaveChanges:=True
```

Pay attention to SaveChanges option, choose True/False if you want to save or not this workbook

Comment: Hello Paulo, Now it is failing from the below step,
Sheets("Peak Utilization History").Select
Range("A1").Select ' In this line you should choose which cell to start pasting
ActiveSheet.Paste

Comment: Failing on what ? Any error message or it doesn`t do the expected ?

Comment: It is throwing an error and when I click on debug, it shows there is a problem from that line.

Comment: Hi Paulo,

Finally, I am able to fix it by adding another line (Workbooks(FileName).Activate).

Application.Workbooks.Open (Path & "book1.xls")
        Sheets(Array("sheet1")).Select
        Sheets("sheet1").Activate
        Cells.Select
        Selection.Copy
        Workbooks(book2.xls).Activate
        Sheets("sheet2").Select
        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
  
Now the challenge is, I want to close book1.xls. What would be the code and where should I place it in the order?

Comment: Thank you soo much Paulo! I am all set now.